# MongoDB + Node.js RegEx find() not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to find everything in a database which contains a specific word. So I decided to use RegEx. But it's not working with a variable. If I use regex without any variables, it works completely perfect. An example for that:

```
app.post("/test", function(req, res){
let tagcontent = req.body.q.tag;
let regexValue = '/'+tagcontent+'/';

  Tags.find({"tagname": /exampletag/}, function(err, tags){

    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }else{
      res.send(tags);
    }

  });
});
```

But when I'm trying to use this query with a variable, MongoDB shows me an empty result. Example:

```
app.post("/test", function(req, res){
let tagcontent = req.body.q.tag;
let regexValue = '/'+tagcontent+'/';

  Tags.find({"tagname": new RegExp(regexValue)}, function(err, tags){

   if(err){
     console.log(err);
   }else{
     res.send(tags);
   }

  });
});
```

What can i do? Thanks for any help.

Comment: You don't need to use the slash `//` when you call the `RegExp` function. So just `RegExp(tagcontent)` without the slashes. Also `{ "tagname": { "$regex": tagcontent } }` also needs no slashes.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked! @NeilLunn